# TinyMCE hide Div's Placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE on my own created TextBox and TextArea.
The thing is that I need to put a placeholder in those divs.

I have tried to implement it.
The thing is that the placeholder is shown when the TinyMCE is not active, 
and when its active, The text editing works as expected but no placeholder is shown.

In addition I need that the placeholder and the input text will be moved 
a little bit left.

Here's a snippet in JSFiddle:

**HTML**

```
<h3>Item Name</h3>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="text-box-styling text-box-area" id="inputItemName"   
         contentEditable=true data-text="Enter text here">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Description</h3>
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="get">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="text-area-styling text-box-area" 
           id="textareaDescription">
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.text-box-styling {
    width: 460px !important;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid 1px #373d42;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.text-area-styling {
    resize:none;
    width: 460px !important;
    height: 60px !important;
    border: solid 1px #373d42;
    border-radius:0px;
    /*margin-bottom: -4px;*/

}

[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
        content:attr(data-text);
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
tinymce.init({
          selector: '.text-box-area',
          plugins: 'autoresize',
          inline: true,
          setup: function (editor) {
              editor.on('focus', function (e) {
                  console.log("focus");
              });

              editor.on('blur', function (e) {
                  console.log("blur");
              });
          },
});
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/Ln631dh3/

Following what I've tried how can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance,

EVH671

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the HTML spec, the `placeholder` attribute works with the following `<input>` types: `text`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, and `password`.  As you are using a `<div>` or other block element you cannot use the `placeholder` attribute to put a "hint" into the `<div>` that will hold TinyMCE.

TinyMCE itself does not have a placeholder attribute that you can specify (in the init or on a tag) but there does appear to be at least one 3rd party plugin that someone wrote to address this issue:

https://github.com/mohan/tinymce-placeholder

Unfortunately that plugin **does not** currently work for inline editing but I am sure you could extend it so that it would work in that scenario.  There is an issue in the GitHub to request that very support.